# Calling a child object in the parent object

Tags: php, oop, call

I want to know if I can create a child object in a parent object an use it...

- I mean is it posible?
- Is it a good    idea?
- What do I have to care if I do    so?

I am using the child classes on their own and i want to use them in a private function of the parent class as well.

thanks

here some source to imagine what I am meaning:

```
class A{
    private $child_class1;
    private $child_class2;

    private function somefunction(){
        $this->child_class1 = new B();
        $this->child_class1->do_something();

        $this->child_class2 = new C();
        $this->child_class2->do_something();
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function do_something(){
...
    }
}

class C extends A{
    public function do_something(){
...
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the obvious syntax errors, have you actually tried it? If so, please clarify the question and point out what didnt work (if it didnt work). Or explain what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: no i didn't try it out so far. i just wanted to know if this is posible and if it's a good idea or not. i could imagine that you should not use this kind of call structure...

Comment: It's hard to take the question seriously when you are creating objects in a loop :-/

Comment: nc3b i don't get you. what do you mean?

Comment: @helle: You actually edited the question to move the functions outside the constructor and now you say you don't get me ? :))

Comment: nc3b sorry for that. i don't get my self about this problem somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be like a bad idea IMHO - it's going to require high maintenance and you are creating some tight couplings between classes.

i would recommend creating an abstract function in the parent that each of the children will implement with it's own logic.

[EDIT] since you are trying to iterate over all child objects i would recommend to create a base class that handles all the logic that needs to be implemented to all children, and override it in each of the child classes that need additional logic, and call the parent function inside it.

Comment: sorry for the wrong source but it was hard to face the problem for me ... that's why i put it in here. 

what do you think about child instances in the parent? bad idea?

Comment: @helle : no doubt :).. try to create code that references classes from other classes as less as you can for loose coupling and easier maintenance in the future

Comment: you mean as long as it is possible by php I should do it as long as it's for better maintainability? so I don't violate any OO principals so far?

Comment: @helle : exactly, in any language for that matter. it may seem like a drag to figure out how to comprise your code to follow those guidelines, but you will soon find out that it makes for a very nice code structure for your program - and it will be well worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You could use abstract methods to delegate certain actions to derived classes:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->do_something();
    }

    protected abstract function do_something();
}

class B extends A {
    protected function do_something() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It is not certainly a good idea to do so. It depends on what you want to achieve, and why. Creating derived classes in the parents constructor (like your previous example stated) is impossible. The language might allow it, but it will lead to an endless loop of instantiation. You will definitely need to explain why you are doing this. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you sufficiently.

Comment: please whatch the changed source code. it was a bad idea to put the instanciation in the constructor ... was just posting very fast...

Answer (score 1):

I think the big question should be why you would want it. I cannot come up with a solid design that would have a class extending something (the default example could be furniture, so for instance GardenChair extending Chair) be available in the parent class.

The whole idea is that it should be the other way around.

If you want to call the 'do_something', you should make an instance of the child, and let it call itself. If you need to enforce the `do_something`, try it like this:

```
public abstract class A{
    public abstract funcion do_something();

    public function __constructor(){
        $this->do_something();
    }

}

public class B extends A{
    public funcion do_something(){
        ...
    }
}

public class C extends A{
    public funcion do_something(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to iterate over all the models (B, C, ...) which inherit from A... (is it a better idea not to do this in A?) but on the other hand i want to use them one by one.